# Allow edit permissions to column B in google sheet using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with 3 sheets
The first sheet has a B column which should be allowed to edit for the user User1@gmail.com

The above user should not be allowed to edit anywhere else other than Sheet1!B column.
No editing in Sheet2 and Sheet3 as well.

Is there a way, to implement this using apps script.

Comment: Why apps script? Use named/protected ranges.

Comment: How to allow editing to only B column using protected ranges?

Comment: There is an option to restrict editing but not allow editing.

Comment: Restrict everything else.

Comment: What if a new sheet is created later?

Comment: Protect it too? You can use an onEdit function, but it can only work retroactively and may not properly restore values (e.g. changes to a multi cell range)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166896/discussion-between-tehhowch-and-code-guy).